# Bing maps WPF c#. The displayed route covers road labels

Tags: c#, wpf, routes, bing-maps, bing

This my map:
[image: my map]

And this is bing's web map:
[image: bing's web map]

As you can see, displayed MapPolyline's routes cover road labels. Is there an option to prevent this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Most examples on the web seem to solve this via a transparent route.

Comment: It's maybe an option, but the colours of the route overlap. If you do a route in bing's web and increase zoom, the labels are above the route..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to be expected. Most mapping platforms render the map using "map tiles" which have the labels rendered right on the tiles. Any data displayed on the map is rendered above the labels since the labels are not separate from the base map. The Bing Maps V8 and Windows UWP Map controls are the first Bing Maps controls to use vector labels. In these controls the labels are separate from the base map tiles and are rendered above all data other than pushpins. The Bing Maps website is using the Bing Maps V8 control. If you want it is possible to use the Bing Maps V8 control in a WPF application via a web browser control. The Bing Maps V8 control is the main control that most developers use and also has more feature than any other Bing Maps control (and most other map APIs). You can find out more about Bing Maps V8 here:

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx

Interactive Code Samples: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#overview

Also, be sure to use the [bing-maps] tag on stack overflow when asking a Bing Maps question so that the Bing Maps team sees it and can respond quicker to

Comment: You are right!, thanks for the info, I was using Bing Maps v7 Interactive SDK.